# GCM Android App Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to learn how Google Cloud Messaging works in Android apps, specifically multicast messaging, so I found a tutorial with source code. Unfortunately I can get the program to compile without error but when it runs, I get a fatal exception. Anyone know what is wrong?

Here is the main activity:

```
    package com.ganyo.pushtest;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

    import static com.ganyo.pushtest.Util.*;
    import static com.ganyo.pushtest.Util.TAG;

    public class PushMainActivity extends Activity {

      private TextView messageTextView;
      private Button sendButton;
      private AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // this is a hack to force AsyncTask to be initialized on main thread. Without this things
        // won't work correctly on older versions of Android (2.2, apilevel=8)
        try {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        initUI();

        AppServices.loginAndRegisterForPush(this);
      }

      private void initUI() {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        messageTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            AppServices.sendMyselfANotification(v.getContext());
          }
        });

        registerReceiver(notificationReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
      }

      /**
       * Receives push Notifications
       * */
      private final BroadcastReceiver notificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
          WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

          /**
           * Take some action upon receiving a push notification here!
           **/
          String message = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
          if (message == null) { message = "Empty Message"; }

          Log.i(TAG, message);
          messageTextView.append("\n" + message);

          alert.showAlertDialog(context, getString(R.string.gcm_alert_title), message);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.gcm_message, message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          WakeLocker.release();
        }
      };

      // this will be called when the screen rotates instead of onCreate()
      // due to manifest setting, see: android:configChanges
      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
      {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        initUI();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(notificationReceiver);
      }

    }
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.ganyo.pushtest"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <permission android:name="com.ganyo.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ganyo.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="com.ganyo.pushtest.PushMainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.ganyo.pushtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="GCMIntentService" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is Appservices:

```
package com.ganyo.pushtest;

import android.content.Context;

import android.util.Log;

import com.apigee.sdk.ApigeeClient;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.DataClient;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.callbacks.ApiResponseCallback;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.callbacks.DeviceRegistrationCallback;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.entities.Device;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.entities.Entity;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.response.ApiResponse;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.utils.JsonUtils;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.push.GCMPayload;
import com.apigee.sdk.data.client.push.GCMDestination;

import java.util.HashMap;

import static com.ganyo.pushtest.Util.*;
import static com.ganyo.pushtest.Settings.*;

public final class AppServices {

  private static DataClient client;
  private static Device device;

  static synchronized DataClient getClient(Context context) {
    if (client == null) {
        if (ORG.equals("<<your org name here>>")) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ORG value has not been set.");
        } else {
            ApigeeClient apigeeClient = new ApigeeClient(ORG,APP,API_URL,context);
            client = apigeeClient.getDataClient();
        }
    }
    return client;
  }

  static void loginAndRegisterForPush(final Context context) {

    if ((USER != null) && (USER.length() > 0)) {
        DataClient dataClient = getClient(context);
        if (dataClient != null) {
            dataClient.authorizeAppUserAsync(USER, PASSWORD, new ApiResponseCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "login response: " + apiResponse);
                    registerPush(context);
                }

                @Override
                public void onException(Exception e) {
                    displayMessage(context, "Login Exception: " + e);
                    Log.i(TAG, "login exception: " + e);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG,"Data client is null, did you set ORG value in Settings.java?");
        }
    } else {
      registerPush(context);
    }
  }

  static void registerPush(Context context) {

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);

    if ("".equals(regId)) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(context, Settings.GCM_SENDER_ID);
    } else {
      if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Already registered with GCM");
      } else {
        AppServices.register(context, regId);
      }
    }
  }


  /**
   * Register this user/device pair on App Services.
   */
  static void register(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device: " + regId);

    DataClient dataClient = getClient(context);
    if (dataClient != null) {

        dataClient.registerDeviceForPushAsync(dataClient.getUniqueDeviceID(), NOTIFIER, regId, null, new DeviceRegistrationCallback() {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Device device) {
        Log.i(TAG, "register response: " + device);
        AppServices.device = device;
        displayMessage(context, "Device registered as: " + regId);
        DataClient dataClient = getClient(context);

        if (dataClient != null) {
            // connect Device to current User - if there is one
            if (dataClient.getLoggedInUser() != null) {
                dataClient.connectEntitiesAsync("users", dataClient.getLoggedInUser().getUuid().toString(),
                                           "devices", device.getUuid().toString(),
                                           new ApiResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "connect response: " + apiResponse);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onException(Exception e) {
                        displayMessage(context, "Connect Exception: " + e);
                        Log.i(TAG, "connect exception: " + e);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG,"data client is null, did you set ORG value in Settings.java?");
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onException(Exception e) {
        displayMessage(context, "Register Exception: " + e);
        Log.i(TAG, "register exception: " + e);
      }

      @Override
      public void onDeviceRegistration(Device device) { /* this won't ever be called */ }
    });
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data client is null, did you set ORG value in Settings.java?");
    }
  }

  static void sendMyselfANotification(final Context context) {
      if (device == null) {
          displayMessage(context, "Device not registered. ORG value set in Settings.java?");
      } else {
          DataClient dataClient = getClient(context);
          if (dataClient != null) {
              GCMDestination destination = GCMDestination.destinationSingleDevice(device.getUuid());
              GCMPayload payload = new GCMPayload();
              payload.setAlertText("Hi there!");

              dataClient.pushNotificationAsync(payload, destination, "google", new ApiResponseCallback() {

                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                      Log.i(TAG, "send response: " + apiResponse);
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onException(Exception e) {
                      displayMessage(context, "Send Exception: " + e);
                      Log.i(TAG, "send exception: " + e);
                  }
              });
          } else {
              Log.e(TAG, "data client is null, did you set ORG value in Settings.java?");
          }
      }
  }

  /**
   * Unregister this device within the server.
   */
  static void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device: " + regId);
    register(context, "");
  }
}
```

Gmcintentservices:

```
    package com.ganyo.pushtest;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;

    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

    import static com.ganyo.pushtest.Settings.GCM_SENDER_ID;
    import static com.ganyo.pushtest.Util.displayMessage;

    public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

      public GCMIntentService() {
        super(GCM_SENDER_ID);
      }

      /**
       * Method called on device registered
       **/
      @Override
      protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered, registrationId));
        AppServices.register(context, registrationId);
      }

      /**
       * Method called on device unregistered
       * */
      @Override
      protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered, registrationId));
        AppServices.unregister(context, registrationId);
      }

      /**
       * Method called on receiving a new message
       * */
      @Override
      protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("data");
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message: " + message);

        displayMessage(context, message);
        generateNotification(context, message);
      }

      /**
       * Method called on receiving a deleted message
       * */
      @Override
      protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        generateNotification(context, message);
      }

      /**
       * Method called on Error
       * */
      @Override
      public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
      }

      /**
       * Issues a Notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
       */
      private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, PushMainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
      }
    }

 Alertdialoguemanager:

package com.ganyo.pushtest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class AlertDialogManager {

  public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
  }
}
```

Util:

```
package com.ganyo.pushtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public final class Util {

  static final String TAG = "com.ganyo.pushtest";
  static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.ganyo.pushtest.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";
  static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

  static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
  }

}
```

Wakelocker:

```
package com.ganyo.pushtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public abstract class WakeLocker {
  private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

  public static void acquire(Context context) {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
        PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE |
        PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "WakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
  }

  public static void release() {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
  }
}
```

Here is the logcat area of the fatal exception:

```
05-01 00:26:52.757: D/AndroidRuntime(166): Shutting down VM
05-01 00:26:52.777: D/jdwp(166): adbd disconnected
05-01 00:26:52.817: I/AndroidRuntime(166): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-01 00:26:53.050: I/ActivityThread(258): Publishing provider com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
05-01 00:26:53.627: I/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.ganyo.pushtest for activity com.ganyo.pushtest/.PushMainActivity: pid=267 uid=10036 gids={3003}
05-01 00:26:54.687: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
05-01 00:26:54.707: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
05-01 00:26:55.467: D/AndroidRuntime(267): Shutting down VM
05-01 00:26:55.467: W/dalvikvm(267): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ganyo.pushtest/com.ganyo.pushtest.PushMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ganyo.pushtest.PushMainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ganyo.pushtest-2.apk]
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ganyo.pushtest.PushMainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ganyo.pushtest-2.apk]
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-01 00:26:55.537: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  ... 11 more
05-01 00:26:55.617: W/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.ganyo.pushtest/.PushMainActivity
05-01 00:26:56.499: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{460133f8 com.ganyo.pushtest/.PushMainActivity}
05-01 00:26:56.687: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x3261a0:0x32625c] in 1336038 ns
05-01 00:26:56.777: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x3265b8:0x326780] in 1506105 ns
05-01 00:26:57.337: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x326788:0x326894] in 951792 ns
05-01 00:26:57.967: D/AndroidRuntime(271): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
05-01 00:26:58.009: D/AndroidRuntime(271): CheckJNI is ON
05-01 00:27:00.377: D/AndroidRuntime(271): --- registering native functions ---
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Downvoted... Nobody is going to do your work for you. Explain what you tried so far and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: Well I have tried changing the target sdk in the manifest and tried looking for the fatal exception in the logcat. I found the fatal exception but am not sure what to do with it. The program shows no errors in the IDE but it crashes.

Comment: First of all please edit the logcat into your question. Don't just link to it. And please only edit in the relevant parts of your logcat.

Comment: It is too long to put in there. I tried posting it but the site said that it is longer than the max allowed characters by itself. I'm really not trying to be lazy or anything and am looking to learn about these things.

Comment: You should edit in the relevant parts of the logcat, in other words only the part where the exception occurs. Everything else is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help so far. The majority of the logcat file is very foreign to me at the moment so I didn't know if anything else was important. I edited the original post for the area of the logcat with the fatal exception. I also tried adding the google play services library to the project to see if that would help but nope.

Comment: After looking at it, could it be a missing apk file?

Comment: The problem according to your `logcat` is this: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ganyo.pushtest.PushMainActivity`. This means that you tried to start this `Activity`, but it is actually missing from your apk. Please check if the `PushMainActivity` exists in your project and if it does please check if the package in your manifest corresponds to the package the `PushMainActivity` is actually in.

Comment: Ok I was wondering about the project paths. Usually all the .java files are in the src file path but instead they are in the java folder. Is this the problem?

Comment: No that should be fine. Just check the `PushMainActivity`, the error is there.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I had to stop for the night to go to work. I'm a lowly bartender trying to learn this stuff in my spare time so people like you are helping me a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be all the .java files in the java folder. Once I redid them in the src path, the program worked correctly.